# How can i display the color of my labels into the content table?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, point, symbology, labeling

The thing is that i need to display labels based on colors but without the symbol. In this case  i'm working with points in Arcgis 10 and the maps needs to display only labels with color-based categories and in the content table the layers display only the symbol.

My question is if its possible to, somehow, the color of my labels to be displayed in the content table?

I hope you can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Not. Sure why you just want them in the table of contents.
I had a similar need but really needed them in a legend.
I had to create a set of polygons(as that was the symbol I wanted in th legend not a point).
One poly for each color in the labels.
The I made a legend with only it in the legend and uncheck the "only visible items"
Turn off the layer. And now you have the (points I assume) with labels and colors. With a (separate) layer in the TOC showing the same colors, and the capability to put those in a legend.
If that is not the outcome you are looking for, please state the reasoning for needing the TOC.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i don't want to have another extra layer to display the leyend. It's a solution and works but i prefer not use extra layers. I found a way to display the legend of the points without display the point itself and is playing with the scale. I put my layers's point in a very high and low display limits so the point is not displayed. It works and i'm happy with the result.

Thanks for your time, Brad.